# Cannot put error in rest api using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

Hello I am trying to put the type value in my mongodb database using rest api. However, it shows an error saying cannot put (404 not found).

app.js

```
app.put('api/types/:_id', function(req,res){
    var id = req.params._id;
    var type = req.body;
    Type.updateType(id, type, {}, function(err, type){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(type);
    });
});
```

type.js

```
module.exports.updateType = function(id, type, options, callback){
    var query = {_id: id};
    var update = {
        name: type.name,
        description: type.description,
        category: type.category
    }

    Task.findOneAndUpdate(query,update, options, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `'/api/types/:_id'` rather than `'api/types/:_id'`

Answer (score 0):

One more issue which causes the mentioned error:

Check if there is any typo mistake in the URL which you are trying to access.

In my case, I tried accessing

```
"/api/users/udpate/:id"
```

instead of

```
"/api/users/update/:id"
```

I have entered **udpate** instead of **update**.So express will not be able to find the route which causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions can be of this issue:

1. Can be a typo in endpoints.

   Instead of this

   "**uesr**/:userId"

   Check for this

   "/user/:userId"
2. Can be a slash missing in starting.

   Instead of this

   **"user**/:userId"

   Add this slash in starting

   "/user/:userId"